# How do I store a musical scale in a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, json, database, database-design

I have this personal project to help me remember some music theory, here's where it's at: I have 36 piano keys. They are labelled like this:

```
C3, C3c D3, D3c, E3, F3, F3c, G3, G3c, A3, A3c, B3, C4, C4c D4, D4c, E4, F4, F4c, G4, G4c, A4, A4c, B4, C5, C5c D5, D5c, E5, F5, F5c, G5, G5c, A5, A5c, B5.
```

C3 is a middle C note C3c is a C sharp note.

[image]

I want to be able to store 'Scales' aka a series of the above keys. I also want to be able to store Chords, a combination of the above keys.

For example I want to store a C major scale which would look like this...

[C3, D3, E3, F3, G3, A3, B3, C3]

I need to store and retrieve these notes using a MySQL database. My original thought was to store these as a JSON array in a plane text field but apparently this is not good practice, although I don't understand why.

What alternative database structure would work for storing indefinite series of patterns like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to store in JSON - then you'll need a linking table.
First, you need table PIANO_KEYS where you'll store all 36 keys with their sorting order, something like this: 
 ID || PIANO_KEY || SORT_ORDER 
Record in this table will look like this: 
 1 || C3 || 1 
Second, you'll need PIANO_SCALES table, where you'll store scales: 
 ID || SCALE_NAME 
After all that you'll need table KEY_SCALE_LINKS, where you'll store links between scales and keys: 
 KEY_ID || SCALE_ID 
You will be able to get all keys from requested scale with this:

```
select k.piano_key
from piano_keys k,
    key_scale_links l
where k.id = l.key_id
    and l.scale_id = :requested_scale_id
order by k.sort_order
```

Comment: I really like that.